# Make CharacterControllers in Unity not collide with each other

Tags: unity

I'm trying to spawn a number of CharacterControllers and have them move around an area, but they keep getting stuck on each other. Is there a way to make them pass through each other while still respecting the terrain's obstructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to probably use rigidbodys and capsule colliders (a script to get them to behave similar to a character controller can be found [here](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=RigidbodyFPSWalker)) and then use [`Physics.IgnoreCollision`](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html) to get them to pass through each other.

Comment: Physics.IgnoreCollision works with CharacterControllers, thanks.

Comment: Also check out this site: answers.unity3d.com (its a pure Unity3D developer site for specific Unity questions)